# Podspec dependency installation

Tags: frameworks, dependencies, cocoapods, podspec

I want to add `SwiftLint` to my framework. In my framework's `.podspec` file, I have added:

```
s.dependency `SwiftLint`
```

What is the next step to see the dependency at work? Is there some sort of command I need to run in the command line to "install" the dependency?

Answer (score 0):

In the project that uses your framework, do `pod update` or just `pod update MyFramework` .